# Parameter 'state' implicitly has an 'any' type redux and TS

Tags: typescript, redux

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a Discord clone because I am interested in making my own chat app. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc1loX80TX8) tutorial to be more specific. So far everything is going great, but in both the `userSlice.ts` and `appSlice.ts` the following error comes up.

```
Parameter 'state' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I searched for the cause, and found something about turning off an extension, but I do not have said extension installed. I also saw you could disable the error in the compiler options, but I'd rather solve it than just ignore it.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        user: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        login: (state, action) => {
            state.user += action.payload;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.user = null;
        }
    },
});

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.user;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

This is the code where the error occurs. I am not sure how to solve the error because I've never seen it before. So how would I go about fixing this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to add type to `(state) => state.user.user` like `(state: SomeType) => state.user.user`.

Comment: You need to declare slice type https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-slice-state-and-action-types.

Comment: Just to clarify, the error is occurring on the second to last line right?